# What's the meaning of preposition 'in' in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

The evidence was seized **in** violation of the law.

I think **in** means — *In a particular way*

&

I think in violation of law means-In a way that's illegal

**I want to know in which sense the preposition has been used.**

Comment: The same way as you used it in **in a way that's illegal**!

Comment: @KateBunting In+A Noun(modifier if any) +of =Can i interpret all the structure(as i mentioned ) in the same way?

Comment: From Oxford Languages: _4. (often followed by a noun without a determiner) expressing a state or condition._ 'Violation of the law' is the condition of the action 'seizing the evidence'.

Comment: It also indicate manner, i think.